# android - eclipse android launch stuck at 100

Tags: java, android, eclipse, launch, showcaseview

I have an android application using google's basegameutils library. When I compile and run the application with only the basegameutils library it runs fine. When I add the espian showcaseview library the launch gets stuck at 100 percent. I have also created another sample application successfully imported the espian showcaseview library and it works absolutely fine. It does not get stuck during the launch and I do not get any errors.

I have tried waiting until process works its way out, but eclipse with become non responsive and even close sometimes.

I am adding the library by right clicking my project > properties > android > add library

My Java Build Path with espian showcaseview library added looks like

[image: My Java Build Path with espian showcaseview library added]

Comment: Does the IDE freezes when it reach 100% or it keeps loading? Are you connected to a real device?

Comment: It freezes the entire Eclipse IDE becomes unresponsive and will sometimes close itself. I am using my physical android galaxy s4 device not an emulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to increase Eclipse memory by changing some `vmargs` in your **[eclipse.ini](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini)** file (more info [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_increase_the_heap_size_available_to_Eclipse%3F))

Here's a quick change for your *eclipse.ini*:

```
-vmargs
-Xms1024m
-Xmx2048m
```